# TBS - Merge string with semicolon into list inside if then statement

Tags: opentbs

When I run the following TBS template (.docx) the single quotes (') still remain on the final docx output.

If I remove these, then special characters like semicolon (;) ruins the template, and not all list elements will be shown.

**How can I keep using special characters and avoid the single quotes (') to appear on my document?**

```
some text here

1.  [onshow;if [onload.missingFileEnabled;noerr] = ’1’; then ' Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

   •    [test.x;block=tbs:listitem]

Aliquam a commodo lacus. Proin elit sapien, ultrices vel odio ac, ultricies ipsum ';magnet=w:p]
```

The relevant php codes:

```php
// Create list data
$contentValues = array("missingFileEnabled" => "1", "testListItem1" => "Test; 1", "testListItem2" => "test 2", "testListItem3" => "test 3");

// Since multiple lists has to be supported, the list is converted into a list of list data.
$listItems = array();
foreach ($contentValues as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'ListItem') !== false && endsWith($key, 'Reservation') === false && endsWith($key, 'Description') === false) {
        //    echo "test<br>";
        $keyParts = explode("ListItem", $key);
        $listItems[$keyParts[0]][] = array("x" => str_replace("'", "’", $value));
    }
}

// Then for each list, we merge the data
foreach ((array)$listItems as $listName => $list) {
    $TBS->MergeBlock($listName, $list);
}

// Show the end file
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, $output_file_name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a conditional field (with parameter `magnet`), it is better in your case to use a conditional block (parameter `when`).

It is more rigorous and easier to read.

Here is what you can do (parameter `block=3*tbs:p` defines a block over 3 paragraphes):

```
1.  [onshow;when [onload.missingFileEnabled;noerr] = ’1’; block=3*tbs:p] Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

   •    [test.x;block=tbs:listitem]

Aliquam a commodo lacus. Proin elit sapien, ultrices vel odio ac, ultricies ipsum
```

Comment: how is a paragraph counted? is that by linebreak or? I have the same issue, so I will test your solution tomorrow! :-)

Comment: You can see the paragraph bounds when you use the Display markers options in Ms Word. A list (with bullets or numbers) is made with paragraphs.